# Syntax error in python code for setMouseCallback() event

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on `setMouseCallback()` *event* in a program for mouse as a paint brush. In the attachment, there is code on right side and Python Shell on Left side. When I run the code there is Syntax error.

How can i fix this error ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `(`, try:

```
img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.uint8)
```